# Attach dynamically a pseudo-class :before to a label inside a component

Tags: css, reactjs, pseudo-class

I want to attach dynamically a pseudo-class :before to a label inside a component whose data come from a db.
I know one cannot manipulate pseudo-class (easily/safely) with JS vanilla. So I think about adding this pseudo-class inside the JSX code.
Is it possible and how to achieve this goal?

```
import React from 'react';

const Comp = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label
        className="label" {/* Common to all Comps */}
        HERE : insert style which allows to défine pseudo-class :before on label 
        which is specific to each component Comp; props.id is an id for 
        each Comp that can be used to create dynamically this class
      >
        {props.labelName}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Comp;
```

I tried another way by simulating a pseudo-class with a span before the label. It works since it is easy to create a class **but** in this case, label and span are not linked and I need to drag&drop the label *with* its pseudo-class, which is easy with pseudo-class and more complicated with two separate elements.

Comment: _"label and span are not linked and I need to drag&drop the label with its pseudo-class"_ - so why don't you put the span _into_ the label then? (A `::before` pseudo element does not get placed "before" the label to begin with, it renders as if it was a _child_ element inserted into the label at the very beginning.)

Comment: The alternative would be to use a pseudo element, that gets its content from a custom data attribute (which you should be able to set/manipulate via JavaScript - can't do that with a `:before` element itself.) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

Comment: @CBroe Yes, nesting span inside label works! I hadn't even thought about that. Thanks!

Comment: I am interested in the alternative, would you mind giving a little more details, please, so that I can test it?

Comment: There's an example on the page I linked to - the `cite` attribute of the blockquote element, gets shown as content of the :after pseudo element.